# facebook api send private message to "likers" from fanpage

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a fanpage in facebook and I'd like to send a private message to each member who "liked" my fanpage. Whoever I'm noob in facebook api. I need some light.

Answer (score 0):

The API doesn't let you access who likes a particular page. It's possible for other object types such as album, photo etc but not page.